# Hide/block/remove trackbacks and pingbacks

Tags: firefox, browser, browser-addons, firefox-extensions

I'm not a blog writer so I don't know anything about trackbacks and pingbacks. I do know that they are helluva distracting when I'm reading through comments on some article.

Is there a Firefox addon or Greasemonkey script to remove/block/hide them?

Comment: What do you mean by trackbacks/pingbacks? I would think they wouldn't be visible on the page.